# Having problems reassigning a variable

Tags: javascript, variables

So my variable timeAmount needs to vary depending upon the game mode (let gamea). Thus, I am trying to reassign `var timeAmount` for each game mode in a ternary, as can be seen below.

```
window.onload = function() {
  var timeAmount = 20,
    display = document.querySelector("#time");
  startTimer(timeAmount, display);

  let gamea = document.querySelectorAll("#words, #words1, #words2");
  for (let i = 0; i < gamea.length; i++) {
    randomnum == 1 ?
      ((gamea[i].style.display = "block"), (timeAmount = 10)) :
      (gamea[i].style.display = "none");
  }
};
```

What do I need to do to `var timeAmount` so that I can change the value for each particular situation? Ie. different game modes.

Comment: Write that ternary as a plain "if"?

Comment: There's no functional programming here, why did you use that tag?

Comment: What is `randomnum`? And why is the assignment to `timeAmount` inside the loop? It doesn't depend on the array element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reassign `timeAmount` before you use it in the call to `startTimer`.

There's also no need to check `randomnum` every time through the loop, since it doesn't change. Set a variable to the display mode, and assign that to all the elements.

```
window.onload = function() {
  var timeAmount = randomnum == 1 ? 10 : 20,
    display = document.querySelector("#time"),
    displayMode = randomnum == 1 ? "block" : "none";
  startTimer(timeAmount, display);

  let gamea = document.querySelectorAll("#words, #words1, #words2");
  for (let i = 0; i < gamea.length; i++) {
    gamea[i].style.display = displayMode;
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks! What about if I want to have more than two modes corresponding to multiple random numbers. For example, if randomnum == 2 then .... and if randomnum == 3 then...    Should I still use a ternary operator in this case?

Comment: You could use `if/else if`, `switch/case`, or an array of values.